# string parsing, separate by comma, unless it is enclosed by apostrophes

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, parsing

I need to parse the following string in Objective-C for iOS app

NSString *htmlString = @"12, 22, 'stringA','', 'stringB, stringC', 2,'stringD'";

I would like to an array like this

```
{
    @12,
    @22,
    @"stringA",
    @"emptySlotInfo",
    @"stringB, stringC",
    @2,
    @"stringD"
}
```

The headache is @"strinb, stringC" because

```
[htmlString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

does not work for the case and the @"'" as separator does not work either.

How can I get necessary components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If it scans a `'`, it knows a string is starting and ignore `,`till it reads the next `'`. if no opening `'` was read, sperate by `,`.

[This cocoawithlove article](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/11/writing-parser-using-nsscanner-csv.html) might be helpful.

---

I made a quick prototype. Most likely there is much to optimize, as I am also not a expert for NSScanner

```
NSString *htmlString = @"12, 22, 'stringA','', 'stringB, stringC', 2,'stringD'";
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:htmlString];

NSString *apostrophe = @"'";    // scanner needs to detect this
NSString *comma = @",";         // scanner needs to detect this
NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", apostrophe, comma]];
BOOL apostropheOpen = NO;       // is the scan location inside a single quoted substring?
NSInteger lastCommaIndex = -1;  // track last found comma's index
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:charSet intoString:NULL];
    NSString *charAtlocation = [htmlString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange([scanner scanLocation], 1)];
    if ([charAtlocation isEqualToString:apostrophe]){
        apostropheOpen = !apostropheOpen;                
    } else if ([charAtlocation isEqualToString:comma]){
        if (!apostropheOpen) {
            [array addObject: [scanner.string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(lastCommaIndex+1, [scanner scanLocation]- lastCommaIndex-1)]];
            lastCommaIndex = [scanner scanLocation];
        }
    }
    [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation]+1];
} ;

// scanner only dealt with the string until the last comma, probably one more value to handle
if (lastCommaIndex < [scanner scanLocation]){
    [array addObject: [scanner.string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(lastCommaIndex+1, [scanner scanLocation]- lastCommaIndex-1)]];
}

// array contains seperated strings, but with blanks and apostrophes
// we will deal with them now
__block NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    obj = [[obj stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]
                stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charSet];
    if ([obj length] > 0)
        [resultArray addObject:obj];
    else
        [resultArray addObject:@"emptySlotInfo"];
}];
```

The resultArray contains

```
(
12,
22,
stringA,
emptySlotInfo,
stringB, stringC,
2,
stringD
)
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems exactly what I need. Good case to learn NSScanner class.