# Splitting a string into an array, where individual items may contain the delimiter

Tags: ios, nsstring

Suppose I have an `NSString` object that contains a list. Included in the list are some quotes, which contain the separator character. How best to split this up into an array?

An example would be a list of names and email addresses, separated by commas:

```
"Bar, Foo" <foo@bar.com>, "Blow, Joe" <joe@Blow.com>
```

I found a solution, but I'm wondering if maybe there's a more efficient solution. My solution was basically this:

- First, parse into a mutable array the string by quote marks.
- For array items with odd indexes, change the commas to tokens.
- Merge the mutable array back into a string.
- Parse the new string into an array using `-componentsSeparatedByString`.
- Loop through the array, replacing the tokens with commas.

It seems like there should be an `NSString` method that does this, but I didn't find one.

For what it's worth, here's my solution:

```
-(NSArray *)listFromString:(NSString *)originalString havingQuote:(NSString *)quoteChar separatedByDelimiter:(NSString *)delimiter {
    // First we need to parse originalString to replace occurrences of the delimiter with tokens.
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfQuotes = [[originalString componentsSeparatedByString:quoteChar] mutableCopy];
    for (int i=1; i<[arrayOfQuotes count]; i +=2) {
        //Replace occurrences of delimiter with a token
        NSString *stringToMassage = arrayOfQuotes[i];
        stringToMassage = [stringToMassage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:delimiter withString:@"~~token~~"];
        arrayOfQuotes[i] = stringToMassage;
    }
    NSString *massagedString = [[arrayOfQuotes valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:quoteChar];
// Now we have a string with the delimiters replaced by tokens.

// Next we divide the string by the delimeter.
    NSMutableArray *massagedArray = [[massagedString componentsSeparatedByString:delimiter] mutableCopy];
// Finally, we replace the tokens with the quoteChar
    for (int i=0; i<[massagedArray count]; i++) {
        NSString *thisItem = massagedArray[i];
        thisItem = [thisItem stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"~~token~~" withString:delimiter];
        massagedArray[i] = thisItem;
    }
    return [massagedArray copy];
}
```

Comment: You might do better splitting the string up using a regular expression: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18799566/535275.

Comment: If that is the only form split on: ">,". Loop through and add back the ">".

Comment: @Zaph, this is just an example. I'm looking for a generic solution to the stated problem, not a specific answer to the example.

Answer (score 0):

It's not NSString you should be looking at, but NSScanner.  Create an NSScanner that will parse the NSString the way you want.  If you know that certain characters will never occur, you can change commas between quotes to one of those characters, then explode the string into an array, then replace the temporary character with a comma.  You can probably create an NSScanner that will do all the parsing if you really get into it.

Comment: Helpful URL: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html

Comment: P.P.S. Of course, using a separator character that isn't in your strings, like tab, would make it even easier.

Comment: Here's an essentially similar question with an `NSScanner` solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903167/string-parsing-separate-by-comma-unless-it-is-enclosed-by-apostrophes/12903308#12903308

I may consider something like this or regex in the future. Neither of these options seems elegant, but maybe there's not an elegant solution.

Comment: I've used NSScanner, and it's actually quite elegant in that it can pick up lots of different sequences and act on them correctly.  And the finished code is easier to read than a regex expression (unless you're a regex guru, which I'm not).